# How can background color to window for Alert Dialog

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

I am making alert dialogue like this in Android Platfrom So Please any Body help me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/avVY0.png

Comment: It will be great if you posted, what you have already tried in order to give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

First create an Activity and design it like a Pop up you have mentioned :

In onCreate() method of the Activity write this code :

```
        DisplayMetrics dm=new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width=dm.widthPixels;
        int height=dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.9), ((int)(height*.6))); //multiply by .9 or .6 defines the width and height of your pop up, you can change it based on your requirement
```

Create a custom theme like this :

```
<style name="AppTheme.TranslucentPopupTheme">

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

Add this in the manifest for this Pop up Activity :

android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TranslucentPopupTheme"

Comment: I will call this Alert Dialog when i can click the button . so help me how can i call this layout

Comment: What you are trying to do is create a customized Popup, you have to create an Activity and in your activity layout file you have to design the Pop up like you want and in your Activity Java class you have to write the code I have mentioned above.

You can open this Pop up like you open and Activity using Intent :

Intent intent=new Intent(context,PopUpActivity.class);
startActvity(intent);